# NA Warning message: In mean.default(.) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning

Tags: r, dplyr

```
mean(mtcars$mpg)
```

[1] 20.09062

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%  
       select(mpg)%>% mean()
```

> [1] NA
>   Warning message: In mean.default(.) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning

Why I could not get the answer when I use `dplyr`?

Comment: you should use `unlist` like so `mtcars %>% select(mpg) %>% unlist() %>% mean()` but I didn't remember why.

Comment: `mtcars %>% pull(mpg) %>% mean()`

Answer (score 0):

As you can see `select` returns a data frame which is not a numeric or logic, so  we get a NA for the mean as an output. You can reproduce the same output with `mean(mtcars)`

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% select(mpg) %>% class()
[1] "data.frame"

mtcars %>% select(mpg) %>% unlist() %>% class()
[1] "numeric"

mtcars %>% select(mpg) %>% unlist() %>% mean()
[1] 20.09062
```